# Failed to build gem native extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have recently tried to install rails via gem by running `gem install rails`. However, it always fails with the following error message.

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: D:/Program Files/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.3/ext/websocket-driver
D:/Program\ Files/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I D:/Program\ Files/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20210303-3696-skc9xl.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: D:/Program Files/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.3/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR=" clean
Makefile:269: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

current directory: D:/Program Files/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.3/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR="
Makefile:269: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Program Files/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.3 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Program Files/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/websocket-driver-0.7.3/gem_make.out
```

Does anyone know what is actually happening here? I would appreciate any answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this "multiple target patterns" error when compile gem extensions is caused by spaces in directory names where you have installed your Ruby or your gems.

Especially on Windows, you should install your Ruby to a directory which contains no spaces, rather than your current location `D:/Program Files/Ruby30-x64`. To fix this, I recommend to uninstall Ruby and install it again to a more appropriate location.

Comment: Thanks, will be trying it

Comment: I've tried moving my Ruby to another directory without spaces in it and changed the environment variables. Now, it's working smoothly. Thank you very much.